# How to customize Haystack's SearchView to accept addtional URL parameters?

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-class-based-views

Given the url conf:

```
r'^(?P<some_var>[-a-z0-9\.]*[a-z0-9\.]\.\w+)/search/$'
```

How do I pass the named group `some_var` to Haystack's SearchView?

I'd like to override `SearchView.get_results()` to do an additional filter depending on `some_var`.

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subclass `SearchView` and override `__call__` which is the "view" part of the class.

```
from haystack.views import SearchView

class MySearchView(SearchView):

    def __call__(self, request, some_var):
        self.some_var = some_var
        return super(MySearchView, self).__call__(request)
```

Then, you can use `self.some_var` in other methods on the class.